# Angular.js app in separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with simple **angular.js** app.
**app.html**

```
<body ng-app="myAct">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-include="'form.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**form.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input ng-model="general"    name="general"></input>
<input ng-model="concrete"   name="concrete"></input>
<button type="button" ng-click="addTk()">Add</button>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myAct', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.arr = [
    ];

    $scope.addTk = function(){
        $scope.arr.push({'general': $scope.general, 'desk': $scope.concrete});
    };
});
```

It doesn't work ( `value of arr = [general:"null", concrete: "null"]` ). But when I copy **form.html** right into **app.html** it works properly.

Comment: `ng-include` doesn't parse the file you are passing in against the current scope;  If you want to make a template like this, it should be a Directive.

Comment: Exactly it have to be in a directive with a template.

Comment: @Claies it could also be done by using dot rule..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are running into is a consequence of how `$scope` inheritance works.

Scopes inherit prototypically from one another, and in this case `ng-include` creates a new scope. This means that it will **inherit properties from the parent.**

The important distinction here is that **primitives are inherited by value, not by reference.**

So your controller is bound to it's own `general` and `concrete` properties, but the template, and subsequent `ng-model` declarations are bound to a set of child properties that do not belong to the parent.

This is why it is recommended to use the [`controller as` syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example) for your controllers and avoid the use of `$scope` completely.

```
//Properties and methods go directly on controller
app.controller('myCtrl', function(){
    var vm = this;        

    vm.arr = [
    ];

    vm.addTk = function(){
        vm.arr.push({'general': vm.general, 'desk': vm.concrete});
    };
});

<!-- Use ctrl as 'ctrl' -->
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
  <div ng-include="'form.html'"></div>
</div>

<!-- Reference via alias 'ctrl' -->
<input ng-model="ctrl.general" name="general"></input>
```

Another way to solve this with minimal changes would be to simply move your `ng-controller` statement directly into the template, [as mentioned by GPicazo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546153/angular-js-app-in-separate-files/31546412#31546412).

Answer (score 0):

Its basically scope issue, because `ng-include` does create a new scope using `transclusion`, you need to follow dot rule while defining `ng-model` that can follow the prototypical inheritance.

**Markup**

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="model.general" name="general"></input>
  <input ng-model="model.concrete" name="concrete"></input>
  <button type="button" ng-click="addTk()">Add</button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myAct', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.model = {}
    $scope.arr = [];

    $scope.addTk = function(){
        $scope.arr.push({'general': $scope.model.general, 'desk': $scope.model.concrete});
    };
});
```

Comment: @Homer whats problem with mine answer?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Pankaj's answer is to move the controller binding into the form.html file like so:

form.html

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input ng-model="general"    name="general"></input>
    <input ng-model="concrete"   name="concrete"></input>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addTk()">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a dot in your expressions in order to preserve the references in JavaScript. The easiest way to do this is to use the `controllerAs` syntax and follow the `prototype` class pattern for your controllers.

The code below will run:

```js
var app = angular.module('myAct', []);

function MyCtrl() {
 
    this.arr = [];
  
};

MyCtrl.prototype.addTk = function(data) {
        this.arr.push(data);
};

app.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myAct">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
            <div ng-include="'form.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="form.html">  
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input ng-model="vm.general" name="general"></input>
  <input ng-model="vm.concrete" name="concrete"></input>
  <button type="button" ng-click="vm.addTk({general: vm.general, concrete: vm.concrete})">Add</button>
  {{vm.arr}}
</div>
</script>

</body>
```